# Identify Huge Mystery Beetle

Tags: species-identification

It is around 2 inches long, one inch wide, fat, hazel coloured with black specks and has short antennae. It's got a lot of cobwebs on its legs, since I found it in a corner in my house. It was found in North America.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Where in North America did you find it? Not the same species live in the Yukon than in the Yucatan. I edited the post to capitalize the first letters of your sentences and add the picture direclty in the post (which you can do with one of the icon above the content of the post when you click on 'edit').

Answer (score 5):

It's a female Eastern Hercules beetle (*Dynastes tityus*). Unlike the male, the female doesn't have 'horns' as it doesn't need to fight in order to find a mating partner. It's the largest and heaviest beetle in North America. It belongs in *Scarabaeidae* or scarab beetles.

[image]

[Source](http://bugguide.net/node/view/2878) from BugGuide.com